# Should I make all types generic for interfaces of classes that I depend upon?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, interface

Ok, so I'm trying to decouple my code. Instead of using singletons all over the place I want to use dependency injection with interfaces. So far so good.

Now, I have this big networking class that uses other networking classes as arguments or return types for its methods. For example:

```
public class Network
{
    void OnServerError(NetworkConnection conection, int errorCode);
}

public class NetworkConnection
{
    public NetworkError lastError { get; }
}

public class NetworkError
{
    public string Error { get; private set; }
}
```

1. Does even make sense to create an interface for the Network class?
2. If so, do I need to make all types generic? For types that are classes with public methods, do I also need to create an interface for it? Basically keep going deeper in the class until everything is either an interface or a generic type?
3. One of the reasons I want to create an interface for this class is that I could maybe switch to a different network lib in the future and I wouldn't want to refactor everything everywhere, although my initial interface will have the same signature of pretty much my existing networking class, so I'd have to maybe refactor it in the future anyway. What am I missing?

Comment: The real question here, is whether your `Network` class is to be injected into other classes too... if so, then it may be useful. As Glenn's answer points out: interfaces aren't required for DI, they're just useful. The real answer is entirely up to you though, it comes down to your requirements. Are you going for constructor or property injection? What container are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to make `Network` an interface to take advantage of dependency injection.

When I'm at this crossroad with a project, when there's no clear reason to extract an interface from my class, I think, "Am I going to want to write a Mock implementation of this type for Testing scenarios?"

In some tests, you may want to simulate a certain scenarios or behaviors.  Mock implementations are really useful for that.

Some classes it makes sense for, but not in every case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: For the Network class I can see that I'll probably want to mock it because I want my unit tests to not depend on network connection and test only what it is responsible to do. If this is the case, should I interface everything?

Comment: Given the cost of extracting an interface is so low (especially if using Resharper), it is not uncommon for many developers to default to interfacing (almost) everything.